# thumbnails video react-native-image-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, video-thumbnails

Currently I'm playing with react-native-image-picker to launch camera either for capture photo or video and display on the thumnbails.

For photo, thumbnails is working just fine but for the video it's only appear a white space.

Here is my code inside pickImage function

-- photo

```
    const source = {uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data, isStatic: true};
    let items = this.state.items;
    items.push({id:items.length, source:source});
    this.setState({items});
```

-- video

```
    const source = {uri: response.uri, isStatic: true};
    let items = this.state.items;
    items.push({id:items.length, source:source});
    this.setState({items});
```

hope you can help me.
Thank you

Comment: did you found the solution for that ? me too searching for the solution

Comment: still no solution found for that.. I already left this for a while focusing on other things.

Comment: :( .  . .. . . .

Comment: after three years, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't work if you are using `Image` component from react-native to show thumbnails for video files. Currently there is no api/component that comes with react-native itself for this purpose. You can generate thumbnails using a third party library like [react-native-create-thumbnail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-create-thumbnail) and show the thumbnails using `Image`.

Comment: Ended up using react native create thumbnail too and it works great so far

Comment: @cherucole How did you display images using <Image> component from the path generated from react native create thumbnail?

Comment: @AstralCloud I think the object generated by the thumbnail library has a uri property that you can use in <Image source={{uri: uri}} style={must have dimensions in style} />. You can confirm by logging the output of create thumbnail and then just display like how you would handle a network image in Image